# How to make my text render higher up on the page?

Tags: css, layout, html

[image]

Now I want the text "(även uppfinnare)" to display at the top row. The HTML that does it now is

```
<div class="data-box">   
            <div class="personName"><strong>    
                3. Kee Marcello&nbsp;
             </strong></div> 
        <div class="otherDetails">(även uppfinnare)</div> 

        <table border="0"><tr><td></td><td>Telefon</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Fax</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>E-post</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>null</td><td>Referens</td><td></td></tr>
        </table> 


    </div>
```

The relevant CSS is

```
.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
.personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  
.otherDetails {     float:right;     width:450px;      }
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: As others have suggested the two div tags will not fit into the space, when you float an element it first tries to go up as high as it can and then tries to go left or right depending on the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply float left both to `.personName` and `.otherDetails` and make sure that `.data-box` width is almost `750px` (`300px + 450px`) or just reduce the size of the 2 side-by-side `div` so the sum of their width is no wider than 650px

Answer (score 1):

It falls down because it doesn't fit on the container. `.data-box` is 650px width, and `.personName` and `.otherDetails` width sums up to 750px

Answer (score 1):

Both your elements are floated (one to the right, one to the left), and together they make up 750px. but the container element is only 650px wide.

when floated elements run out of space, they get shuffled to the next line.

either make the children elements smaller (to fit into 650px) or make the parent bigger(750px)